# Upload Images in CodeIgniter 2, sometimes, fails

Tags: codeigniter, upload, pixel

I have a X Files problem. When I upload Image, sometimes, the image is upload only one pixel, in general, is ok the upload image but this problem is randomly.

I use the library Upload, I use log for every step but, all is ok.

Is possible a bug for the libary Upload or version of CodeIgniter? I use the version 2.1

Comment: please recheck your codes. There is no reported error in library upload.

Answer (score 0):

please recheck your codes. There is no reported error in library upload in CI 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

How I know the size of a file where this is located in another directory? One solution I think is know the size of file (I have a min_size) and if the size is lower, show a message error and delete the image.